# Custom Add to Cart

Tags: php, magento, cart

I want to add an item to the cart, but if this item is already in the cart, Magento by default just increases the quantity of this item. I want to add a new row in the database table `sales_flat_quote_item` where magento saves its cart items. The reason why I want to do this is to show in the cart page the 2 or more items in different rows, for some reason.
I tried to track the flow of magento in saving the cart, but I ended up with this code: `Mage::dispatchEvent('sales_quote_product_add_after', array('items' => $items));`
I'm trying to find where is this method, but I cant find it. I hope that the solution that I've been searching for is here. Does anyone know where this method is located? Or, if I'm wrong with my assumption, what might be the solution to my problem?

Answer (score 0):

This is the call of magento event which calls other module methods one by one that have registered for listen to that event. So you need to look every `config.xml` file of every module for `sales_quote_product_add_after` string under `<events>` tag. For more about events and observers in magento go to:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/0_-_module_development_in_magento/customizing_magento_using_event-observer_method

Default magento implementation has no observers for this event and it wouldn't lead you to the solution. Check [this blog post](http://www.ecomdev.org/2012/12/12/magento-checkout-shopping-cart-flow.html) about the cart flow, especially the part entitled 'Quote Model Adds a New Item or Changes Existing One Qty'